# Matrices and diagonalization.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

I could verify that $P$ statement is false by just calculating the determinant but couldn't answer $Q$ statement. Any clue about $Q$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\;Q,D\;$ are matrices, the first one invertible and the second diagonal, with

$$D=Q^{-1}SQ=Q^{-1}\left(I-5T)Q\right)=I-5Q^{-1}TQ$$

and $\;T\;$ is diagonal, too.

Answer (score 0):

$T = \frac 15(I - S)$. Since adding a multiple of $I$ to any matrix only shifts the eigenvalues but does not change the eigenvectors, $T$ is also diagonalizable.

For more detail, suppose $S = U\Lambda U^{-1}$ is the eigendecomposition (so $\Lambda$ is diagonal). Then
$$T = \frac 15(I - U\Lambda U^{-1}) = U\left(\frac 15 I - \frac 15 \Lambda \right)U^{-1}.$$
The matrix $\frac 15 I - \frac 15 \Lambda$ is diagonal because $I$ and $\Lambda$ are.